# Third party libraries Conflicts in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using Yii2 for my web application.
I have used Google-client library and other third party library.
When I run the script, it throws an error.
If I use any one of them at a time then it works fine.

Libraries are called in `/web/index.php`
I want to know how to call a library separately for single script only.

Like by including in page in CorePHP.

In Yii2 I am unable to include in top of controller.

Comment: grammar fixed

tags removed

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect way to include 3rd-party libraries direct to entry script ( /web/index.php) or controller file.
Correct way assumes to add libraries using [composer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html).

If your library is not released as a Composer package, you can unpack it directly to vendor directory. More details see here:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-downloaded-libs

Answer (score 1):

"If a library carries its own class autoloader, you may install it in the entry script of your application. It is recommended the installation is done before you include the Yii.php file so that the Yii class autoloader can take precedence in autoloading classes." - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html